# Increment an iterator c++

Tags: c++, iterator, increment

My problem is as follows: I use an iterator, and I want to compare each element to the next element. Prototype looks like below, how can I increase the iterator to be able to compare? 
Also, how can I set a proper condition for this to happen? I mean how to point on the last element, not on the next after the last like with end() function:

```
std::vector<T>::const_iterator it;
std::vector<T>::const_iterator it2;
for (it = set.begin(), it != set.end(); it++)
{
  // some things happen
  if ( final == it )
  {
     if ( it != set.end()-1 ) // how to write properly condition?
     {
        it2 = it + 1; //how to assign the next here?
        if (...)//some condition
        {
          if ( it->func1() - it2->func1()) < 20 ) //actual comparison of two consecutive element values
            // do something
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with those multiple iterators?

Comment: I'm using till now just one iterator (this is just part of code). I want to be able to compare func1 of two consecutive in the set. so I need one iterator pointing on actual, one on the next one. is there a better approach? I might have done some overkill here, plz correct me

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826893/how-do-i-loop-over-consecutive-pairs-in-an-stl-container-using-range-based-loop/14827924#14827924) to this recent question [*How to loop over consecutive pairs in an STL container?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14826893/1084416).

Comment: for `set.end()-1`, use `set.rbegin()`

Answer (score 6):

In **C++11** use the functions [std::next()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/) and [std::prev()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/).

Your code could become:

```
// before
it != std::set.end()-1

// after
it != std::prev(set.end())
```

and

```
// before
it2 = it + 1;

// after
it2 = std::next(it);
```

That is true also for non-vector containers, such as map,set or others.

NOTE: after `std::next(it)`, "it" iterator remains unmodified!

NOTE 2: Use `it2 = std::next(it,n);` to increment as much as you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to solve that. You should use the second form of that function (with predicate) and pass to the predicate your `some things happen` and `some condition` in c-tor

```
auto found = std::adjacent_find( set.begin(), set.end(),
    [some_comdition]( const T & left, const T & right ) {
        if ( some_comdition ) {
            if ( left.func1() - right.func1() < 20 ) {
                do_smth();
                // return true; if there's no need to continue
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that `it++` is acceptable, we should define a new iterator called `itplusone`, which is initialized as `itplusone = ++it`. In this way, you can safely use the meaning of an iterator pointing to the next item of `it`. Also clearly, the range of iterator of `itplusone` bounded by terms `itplusone != set.end()`. I use this method to compute the total weight of a path, which is defined as a list  object.

Answer (score -1):

In the `for` loop, you use `it++` which means `it = it + 1`, which is perfectly ok. So this one will be fine also `it2 = it + 1`. `it2` will be pointing to the next value.

In the `for` loop again, you use `it != set.end()`, which is again perfectly ok. So you can also `it + 1 < set.end()`, just like you did in your code.

I don't see anything wrong in your code, just wanted to explain.

Comment: That's true for `std::vector`, but in general, `it++` does **not** mean `it = it + 1`. All iterators support increment, but only random access iterators support addition.

Comment: I may want use it for other containers also, so that's my problem, how to assign the next element to my new iterator. I pointed in the answers above this problem with number

Answer (score -1):

somewhat late, just discovered it, but like mentioned above, ++ iterator works fine.

```
vector<string> P
auto itA = begin(P);

while(itA != end(P))
{
    if(itA != end(P))
    {   
        ++itA; // 
    } 
}
```